# Why is the key generated from Kafka JDBC Source Connector getting prefixed with an L?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to configure Kafka connect to generate a key for messages that are generated from an Oracle 19c table. I have experienced some unexpected behavior while trying to follow the setup shown in [Confluent's docs](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/source-connector/index.html#message-keys). When chaining the ValueToKey SMT with the ExtractField SMT on a VARCHAR field my key is prefixed by an L and and some empty Unicode characters.
This is my message that Kafka Connect produces:

```
    [{
      "topic":"BUSINESS_AUD",
      "partition":0,
      "offset":9,
      "timestamp":1617723230767,
      "timestampType":"CREATE_TIME",
      "headers":[],
      "key":"\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0002L{B4832FC8-BBCF-488C-9720-97C4D3283FEF}",
      "value":{
         "AUD_ID":{
            "long":11042260
         },
         "REV":{
            "long":80325258
         },
         "ID":{
            "long":31549560804
         },
         "BUSINESSID":{
            "string":"{B4832FC8-BBCF-488C-9720-97C4D3283FEF}"
         },
         "BUSINESS_PROPERTY_LU_ID":{
            "long":24
         },
         "VALUE":{
            "string":"business value"
         },
         "DTYPE":"VERSION"
      }
   }]
```

This is my source schema:

```
    create table AUDITDB.BUSINESS_AUD
(
    AUD_ID                  NUMBER(38)   not null
        constraint PKBUSINESS_AUD 
            primary key,
    REV                     NUMBER(38)   not null
        constraint FKBUSINESS_AUD
            references AUDITDB.REVISION,
    REVTYPE                 NUMBER(3),
    ID                      NUMBER(38),
    BUSINESSID                   VARCHAR2(38),
    BUSINESS_PROPERTY_LU_ID NUMBER(38),
    VALUE                   VARCHAR2(1200) default NULL,
    DTYPE                   VARCHAR2(15) not null
)
```

This is how I'm configuring the jdbc connector:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8083/connectors -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
    "name": "jdbc_source_oracle_BUSINESS_AUD",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "errors.log.enable": true,
        "errors.log.include.messages": true,
        "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.0.8:7511:t1fnet",
        "connection.user": "oracleUser",
        "connection.password": "oracleUserPassword",
        "mode": "incrementing",
        "incrementing.column.name" : "AUD_ID",
        "numeric.mapping" : "best_fit",
        "poll.interval.ms": "5000",
        "transforms":"createKey,ExtractField",
        "transforms.createKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
        "transforms.createKey.fields":"BUSINESSID",
        "transforms.ExtractField.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
        "transforms.ExtractField.field":"BUSINESSID",
        "query" : "SELECT CAST(DMDA.AUD_ID AS NUMBER(18)) AS AUD_ID, CAST(DMDA.REV AS NUMBER(18)) AS REV, CAST(DMDA.ID AS NUMBER(18)) AS ID, DMDA.BUSINESSID, CAST(DMDA.BUSINESS_PROPERTY_LU_ID AS NUMBER(18)) AS BUSINESS_PROPERTY_LU_ID, DMDA.VALUE, DMDA.DTYPE FROM AUDITDB.BUSINESS_AUD DMDA",
        "topic.prefix": "BUSINESS_AUD"
    }
}'
```

I'm not sure where the L is coming from. When I try the same setup with a NUMBER field, like ID, I just get Unicode garbage out:

```
[{
    "topic":"BUSINESS_AUD",
    "partition":0,
    "offset":24149,
    "timestamp":1617732719435,
    "timestampType":"CREATE_TIME",
    "headers":[
       
    ],
    "key":"\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0002�����\u0001",
    "value":{
       "AUD_ID":{
          "long":11205147
       },
       "REV":{
          "long":81016468
       },
       "ID":{
          "long":31549704671
       },
       "BUSINESSID":{
          "string":"{03E796CC-C0AB-4CBD-930E-CA99D9A31362}"
       },
       "BUSINESS_PROPERTY_LU_ID":{
          "long":17
       },
       "VALUE":{
          "string":"{03E796CC-C0AB-4CBD-930E-CA99D9A31362}"
       },
       "DTYPE":"VERSION"
    }
 }]
```

I'm fairly sure the issue is in how I'm using the ExtractField SMT since when I remove that SMT from the chain it produces what I'm expecting from the ValueToKey SMT:

```
[{
  "topic":"BUSINESS_AUD",
  "partition":0,
  "offset":27311,
  "timestamp":1617733541872,
  "timestampType":"CREATE_TIME",
  "headers":[
     
  ],
  "key":{
     "BUSINESSID":{
        "string":"{C2D8CAA4-C964-4AFE-B194-21651187BD23}"
     }
  },
  "value":{
     "AUD_ID":{
        "long":11213627
     },
     "REV":{
        "long":81114719
     },
     "ID":{
        "long":31549717943
     },
     "BUSINESSID":{
        "string":"{C2D8CAA4-C964-4AFE-B194-21651187BD23}"
     },
     "BUSINESS_PROPERTY_LU_ID":{
        "long":24
     },
     "VALUE":{
        "string":"businessValue"
     },
     "DTYPE":"VERSION"
  }
}]
```

This leads me to believe that ExtractField is having difficulty with the object that is output from ValueToKey, I'm just not sure what to change to get the interaction I expected.

I'm really stuck here and any help with this will be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you printing those messages? In particular, I'm confused why you have outer array brackets. Also, what converters are you using? JSONConverter with schemas disabled or Avro?

Comment: I'm letting the JDBC Connector generate the avro I can provide that if you want. Those messages are downloaded from the Control Center as plain text.

Comment: Your keys are strings (or ints), right? So why use Avro converter for that?

Comment: Also, you should try using console consumer to rule out control center bugs that might assume keys shouldn't be deserialized in Avro format and just shows utf8 strings

Comment: So the intent was for the JDBC connector to create the avro schema for other application to use and consume the data from, and to create a contract between the services.

Comment: I understand that, but if your keys are primitive types, you don't need schemas for those, only the record values (the database columns)

Comment: So can I specify a different converter for the Key JSON, than the value Avro?

Comment: Indeed, you can, however it isn't JSON either

Comment: Okay StringConverter worked for me. If you want to put "Use String converter. Why you use Avro key converter dummy" in an answer I'll tag it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm going to say the the shown output is a bug in using Avro for the keys (or, at least for primitive fields like strings or ints)

I'm not sure about the L, but it's the result from UTF8 decoding of the binary data

The prefix `\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001` is `0x0` + `(int 1)`, which is the schema ID that you have for `BUSINESS_AUD-key` in the registry.

In general, since keys are rarely structured types, you should try using the [respective `key.converter` class for the type you're extracting](https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/converters), for example  `StringConverter`